# If $A$ and $B$ $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries such that $B+AB=A^2+BA^2+ABA$, $C=A+B+AB+BA+I$ and $A+BA=B^2+AB^2+BAB$. Then,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices with complex entries such that $B+AB=A^2+BA^2+ABA$, $C=A+B+AB+BA+I$ and $A+BA=B^2+AB^2+BAB$. Then which of the following is/are incorrect

(A) $A=B$

(B) $A+B=O$

(C) $B+C^{-1}=I$

(D) $C^{-1}=I+B$

where $C^{-1}$ denotes inverse of matric $C$

**My Approach:**

If I subtract  $A+BA=B^2+AB^2+BAB$ from $B+AB=A^2+BA^2+ABA$, thenI obtain $(A-B)+(BA-AB)=(B^2-A^2)+(AB^2-BA^2)+(BAB-ABA)$ which is true if $A=B$. Also I don't know weather my assumption is correct or not.

Please anyone here guide me to correct approach or post a solution to this post

Comment: Searching approach0 for the $B+AB$ and $A+BA$ identities, you get [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1379221p7637794) and [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1378513p7631040).